# Create a Coupon In BigCommerce Using API

Tags: php, api, bigcommerce

I am trying to create a coupon in big commerce using their API. I am using the following code after connecting with the store.

```
$coupon = array('name' => 'somecoupon', 'type' => 'percentage_discount', 'amount' => '50.0', 'code' => '50off', 'enabled' => true);
echo Bigcommerce::createCoupon($coupon);
```

I simply copied the code from their
[Support Page](http://developer.bigcommerce.com/quickstarts/php)

All the other codes on that page work but create coupon doesnt work. If I use get coupons codes, they work perfectly but creating coupon is not working what so ever. Any ideas on this?

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The developer page neglects to mention that 'applies_to' is also a required field, hence why your code is failing.

Try

```
$coupon = array('name' => 'somecoupon', 'type' => 'percentage_discount', 'amount' => '50.0', 'code' => '50off', 'enabled' => true, 'applies_to'=> array('entity'  => 'categories', 'ids' => array('value' => 0)));
echo Bigcommerce::createCoupon($coupon);
```